# Porting PHP Curl request to C#

Tags: c#, php, curl

Repeat PHP Curl request on C#

I'm trying to send a request to the server whois, using Curl on C#.

I have php function, that works perfectly!

```
function sendRequest()
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://whois.ripn.net");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 43);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "ya.ru\r\n");
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

I try to repeat it in C #, but nothing works.

```
class curl {

    private static Easy easy;
    private static string SockBuff;

    public void CurlInit()
    {

        Curl.GlobalInit((int)CURLinitFlag.CURL_GLOBAL_ALL); 

    }

    public void req()
    {
        easy = new Easy();
        SockBuff = "";

        try
        {
            Easy.WriteFunction wf = new Easy.WriteFunction(OnWriteData);

            easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_URL, "http://whois.ripn.net");
            easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_PORT, "43");
            easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, "10");
            easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "ya.ru\r\n");
            easy.SetOpt(CURLoption.CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, wf);               

            easy.Perform();
            easy.Cleanup();

        }
        catch
        {

        }
        Console.Write(SockBuff);

    } 

    public static Int32 OnWriteData(Byte[] buf, Int32 size, Int32 nmemb, Object extraData)
    {
        // Console.Write(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf));
        SockBuff = SockBuff + System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf);

        return size * nmemb;
    } 

}
```

Why my C# code don't work?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Just an empty string in the response.